# Is there a general refactoring/transformation to turn C macro arguments into function equivalents?

Tags: c, macros, refactoring

I'm resurrecting an [old project](https://github.com/thoni56/c-xrefactory), actually the first refactoring browser to cross the [Refactoring Rubicon](http://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoringRubicon.html).

The source is full of macros, macros that I'd like to turn into testable and mockable functions.

We've established that since macros are much richer semantically than C functions, there is no general approach to convert *any* macro to a function. But often macros are only straight sequential C-code that for some reason is implemented as a macro.

In this case it is mostly a matter of transforming the macro arguments to function argument semantics.

I'm hoping someone might have an idea, or approach, or pointers, to something that is a somewhat general pattern on how to do that. It's fine if it creates a lot of extra indirection, once I get it into a function I can mock and refactor to a more simple form.

My cases are typically something like this

```
#define GetChar(cch, ccc, ffin, bbb) {                              \
    if (ccc >= ffin) {                                              \
        (bbb)->next = ccc;                                          \
        if ((bbb)->isAtEOF || getCharBuf(bbb) == 0) {               \
            cch = -1;                                               \
            (bbb)->isAtEOF = true;                                  \
            goto endOfFile;                                         \
        } else {                                                    \
            ccc = (bbb)->next; ffin = (bbb)->end;                   \
            cch = * ((unsigned char*)ccc); ccc ++;                  \
        }                                                           \
    } else {                                                        \
        cch = * ((unsigned char*)ccc); ccc++;                       \
    }                                                               \
}
```

with a typical invocation like

```
char *fn;
char *ccc;
char *ffin;
CharacterBuffer *iBuf;

GetChar(fn[i],ccc,ffin,iBuf);
```

(Yeah, I know, I'm on a rescue mission, right...)

So I'm looking for "mechanical" transformation rules for the arguments, which would require indirection of course.

Comment: It's very difficult in general because macros don't obey the same rules as functions. For instance, given the name of a variable, you can change the variable. You can declare a function whose name is the result of pasting together the variable's name with some other token. You can stringize the name of the variable. None of these are possible in a function.

Comment: True. In my case none of the string manipulation is used. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: There cannot be such a transformation, as macros are semantically more rich than functions. You can turn any specific macro application into a function, but there is no way whatsoever to turn a generic macro into some testable function. I think you're overreaching the TDD scope here.

Comment: @SK-logic As I’ve tried to explain in the question, I’m not reaching for the ultimate transformation, only arguments.

Comment: Your example seems broken, it assigns pointer value to int.

Comment: Ok, then you should unit-test the macro expansion *output*, not the macro itself. Use, say, `clang-format` after `clang -E` to normalise the output before diffing.

Comment: @SK-logic That’s an interesting approach. I’ll experiment with that. But I am also looking for ways to ”mechanically” transform macros (that actually are only simple sequential code, no use of ”flexible” macro tricks) into functions. To do that all I think I need is a pattern for that transformation.

Comment: @hyde As I stated that’s not a real example, just wanted to convey the idea of ehatbthe body of a typical macro I have looks like. I.e. no fancy macro stuff.

Comment: I'd still fix the example. Having broken example makes it impossible to give a sane answer using the code in in the question.

Comment: Also it'd be good to show what kind of function would you like to convert that macro to.

Comment: @hyde Fair enough, good points. Although I wanted more generally applicable approaches (for the limited type of macros I'm looking at), starting with a concrete example is often a good starting point. Particularly since we've established that there is no general approach, and possibly breaking new ground here. I've included a real example.